# BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync: Received Invalid Column Length from bcp Client for colid N

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

So I was running the following code:

```
await _internalDb.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(results, bulkConfig, (progress) =>
                {
                    log.BulkUpsertProgress(progress);
                });
```

And I got the following exception:

```
Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid 4
```

Now I am trying to determine what column is causing this problem. So after researching, I came across this site: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/received-invalid-column-length-from-bcp-client-for-volid-n1

Now I wrapped the above code into a try catch block:

```
try
            {
                await _internalDb.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(results, bulkConfig, (progress) =>
                {
                    log.BulkUpsertProgress(progress);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = string.Empty;
                if (ex.Message.Contains("Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid"))

                {
                    string pattern = @"\d+";
                    Match match = Regex.Match(ex.Message.ToString(), pattern);
                    var index = Convert.ToInt32(match.Value) - 1;

                    FieldInfo fi = typeof(SqlBulkCopy).GetField("_sortedColumnMappings", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    var sortedColumns = fi.GetValue(bulkcopy);
                    var items = (Object[])sortedColumns.GetType().GetField("_items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(sortedColumns);

                    FieldInfo itemdata = items[index].GetType().GetField("_metadata", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    var metadata = itemdata.GetValue(items[index]);
                    var column = metadata.GetType().GetField("column", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(metadata);
                    var length = metadata.GetType().GetField("length", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(metadata);
                    message = (String.Format("Column: {0} contains data with a length greater than: {1}", column, length));
                }
                return message;
            }
```

Now, where I am stuck at this point is how to replace the BulkCopy. So what I would like to do is to clearly define the exception and find out what column/value is causing the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you using? `BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync` is not EF function.

Comment: But if I go into that definition, I see that it is coming from class EFCore.BulkExtensions